# URL rewrite to another folder and file for specific requests

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting, apache2

I have following directory structure on my local LAMP:

- www

  - basic

    - app

      - router.php
    - public

      - index.html
      - .htaccess

and i can access my index page with `localhost/basic/public/` and i am not using any virtual hosts.

Now i am trying to do two things:

1: instead of `localhost/basic/public/` URL should look like `localhost/basic/` to access homepage.

2: all requests to `/api/` should be redirected to `router.php`. For example if I make a request like `/api/user/login` it should go to `app/router.php` where i can execute specific code according to request for api.

To achieve this i was trying do something like following in .htaccess file but its not working:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api/ [NC]
RewriteRule . ../app/router.php [NC,L]
```

Also i am not sure if we can use relative paths in `RewriteRule`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To summarize, you want:

- There is a special case: If an url starts with /basic/api, you want it to go to the router.php page
- By default, an url that isn't a file should be searched for in public.

In addition you can redirect requests that go to /basic/public/something to /basic/something

---

Put this in a file .htaccess in the basic folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /preview/

#Special case: api requests
RewriteRule ^api/ app/router.php [L]

#Default case: all public files
#Alternativelly use RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/basic/public
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/public/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

#Optionally prevent both localhost/basic/public/file and localhost/basic/file
#outputting the same
#Using THE_REQUEST trick to only match external requests
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(POST|GET)\ /basic/public/
RewriteRule ^public/(.*)$ $1 [R,L]
```

This will do the following:

`localhost/basic/api/user/something` gets internally rewritten to `localhost/basic/app/router.php`

`localhost/basic/something` gets internally rewritten to `localhost/basic/public/something`

`localhost/basic/public/something` gets externally redirected to `localhost/basic/something` (and is then internally rewritten)

Screencast of behaviour: http://www.screenr.com/9GUN

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. public part is working fine now but i am having problem with api. when i goto `localhost/basic/api/test` instead of requesting `/basic/app/router.php` it is requesting `/basic/public/app/router.php`. in api case public should not be there. any idea why?

Comment: In the second rule I had `%{REQUEST_URI}` instead of `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}`. This was incorrect * sends himself off to corner of shame *. Assuming that router.php does exist under the app folder it should work if you change that.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Everything is working perfectly now. Thank you very much for your help.